# How to implement function/process polymorphism in Elixir

Tags: polymorphism, elixir

I want to 'extend' a built-in IO/File functions of Elixir in several (independent) ways.

I came up with the following code pattern:

```
defmodule FileExtension1 do
  # arguments are different for different extensions,
  # but I guess I could just stick with single map/list
  # argument for uniformity 
  def open!(filename, some_param \\ true) do
    filename
      |> File.open!
      |> attach(some_param)
  end

  def close(io) do
    io |> File.close
  end

  def attach(io, some_param \\ false) do
    spawn_link fn ->
      file_manager(io, some_param)
    end
  end

  def detach(io) do
    io |> send {:detach, self}
    receive do
      {:will_detach, ^io} -> :ok
    end
  end

  defp file_manager(io, some_param, state \\ <<>>) do
    if Process.alive?(io) do
      receive do
        {:detach, sender} ->
          sender |> send {:will_detach, self}
        {:custom_request, sender, reference, count} ->
          # {result, new_state} = do_job(...)
          sender |> send {:custom_reply, reference, result} 
          file_manager(io, some_param, new_state)
        {:io_request, sender, reference, {:some_pattern}} ->
          # {result, new_state} = do_job(...)
          sender |> send {:io_reply, reference, result}
          file_manager(io, some_param, new_state)
        x ->
          io |> proxy(x)
          file_manager(io, some_param, state)
      end
    end
  end

  defp proxy(io, data) do
    {request_type, original_from, original_reference, command} = data
    reference = make_ref
    io |> send {request_type, self, reference, command}
    receive do
      {response_type, ^reference, result} -> original_from |> send {response_type, original_reference, result}
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, it does the following:

- Handles custom IO requests in accordance with custom protocol
- Modifies processing of some of standard IO requests
- Proxies everything else to underlying `File`

Now I can transparently stack these things on top of each other (i.e. `attach` first one to the `File`, then second one to the first one, etc.).

The problem is: now I have three modules which follows the same pattern I described above. I want to somehow remove code duplication.

What should I look into?

- Just create another module with shared functions? Like `IO` contains shared functions for several devices, or `Enum` contains shared functions for several types. Could you give me a small example how that would work in my case?
- Protocols? I don't quite understand how protocols could be used here, because what I'm trying to achieve doesn't fall into 'use some function for different (built-in) types' pattern.
- Behaviours? Looks like I could benefit from creating some variation of `GenServer`, tuned to my needs. Then again, if I should use that, small example will help here.

Bonus question: How do I test that shared functionality using `ExUnit`?

Comment: Why are you creating different functions?  If you need different behavior for different file extensions, just pass the behavior in.  Seriously--simply pass in the function to handle the file extension.  You're making it a lot harder than it has to be.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I like that idea. Could you add a really minimalistic example as an answer?

Comment: If I get time, yes, I'll add an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple example of passing a function to another function:

```
#PassInFunction
defmodule PIF do
  def hello(name), do: IO.puts("Hello #{name}!")
  def execf(name, f), do: f.(name)
end

PIF.execf("Onorio",&PIF.hello/1)
```

In your particular case I'd use the file type (or extension as the case may be) to determine which function to pass in.